# Setup an aerospike high-availbilty cluster?

Tags: high-availability, aerospike

Are there any guide to set up an aerospike HA? I had search google but there was no possible result in return.

Look like Aerospike is not really popular in common.

P/s: Lab purpose so there only need 2-3 node/host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aerospike's HA setup is one of the easiest. No need to setup sharding or failover policies. Everything is automatically taken care of. You just need to configure the nodes to see each other and boot them. I suggest to go with 'mesh' mode configuration. Ref: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/network/heartbeat/index.html

Comment: Does the access-address also automatic failover or I have to make an automatic FO with VIP ?

Comment: access-address and automatic failover are independent things. access-address is published to client for cluster discovery. So, if a node goes down and the automatic failover takes care of things, clients will automatically figure out the new cluster and all will be good.